# Pandas DataFrame- By row, conditionally replace multiple column values with last column value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having difficultly finding a solution to a pandas dataframe problem.

**The problem:**  By row in a pandas dataframe, if a cell is equal to 1, replace it with the cell value found in the last column of the dataframe.  I have the initial dataframe constructed and filled, but haven't been able to move on to the next step.

**The dataframes:**  An example of the dataframe (initial and finished):

Intitial_dataframe:

```
       fNum  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  labelx
Index                                   
1         1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0       2
2         1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0       2
4         1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0       3
5         1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       0
6         1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0       3
7         1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0       3
1         2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0       2
2         2  1  1  1  0  0  0  0       2
3         2  1  1  1  0  0  0  0       2
4         2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0       2
5         2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0       0
6         2  0  0  0  0  1  1  1       3
7         2  0  0  0  0  1  1  1       3
```

Finished_dataframe:

```
       fNum  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  labelx
Index                                       
1         1  0  2  2  2  0  0  0       2
2         1  0  0  2  2  0  0  0       2
4         1  0  0  0  0  0  3  0       3
5         1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       0
6         1  0  0  3  0  0  0  0       3
7         1  0  0  0  3  0  0  0       3
1         2  0  2  0  0  0  0  0       2
2         2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0       2
3         2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0       2
4         2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0       2
5         2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0       0
6         2  0  0  0  0  3  3  3       3
7         2  0  0  0  0  3  3  3       3
```

**The latest path attempted:**

```
dfIX = Intitial_dataframe.ix[:, 2:8] #<--The "body" of the data
labelx_frame = Intitial_dataframe.ix[:, 8:9] #<-- The labelx column
dfIX[dfIX>0] = labelx_frame  #<-- Attempt to replace values, nan instead
```

This give nan for all cells with a 1 previously.

**The sincere request for help:**
I am very new to pandas and python, and have spent several hours flailing about reading over pandas and dataframe operations to no avail.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: You seem to be new to StackOverflow, so please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of this site. We don't bite, provided that a bit of effort is shown on your behalf.

Comment: Thank you for the help in improving my question.  I'll continue to attempt to make it more coherent and engaged.  I've made some edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated part of your data since the input data was originally posted as a picture, not copyable text. I'll leave it to you to adjust this approach to your specific data.

Here is the easiest and undoubtedly most readable way to do it, using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({1: [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1], 2: [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0], 3: [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0], 'label_x': [2,2,3,0,0,2,3,2,2,2]})
>>> df
   1  2  3  label_x
0  0  1  1        2
1  0  1  1        2
2  0  1  0        3
3  1  1  1        0
4  1  0  0        0
5  0  0  0        2
6  0  0  0        3
7  1  0  1        2
8  0  1  1        2
9  1  0  0        2
>>> for c in df:
...     if c != 'label_x':
...         df[c] = np.where(df[c] == 1, df['label_x'], df[c])
... 
>>> df
   1  2  3  label_x
0  0  2  2        2
1  0  2  2        2
2  0  3  0        3
3  0  0  0        0
4  0  0  0        0
5  0  0  0        2
6  0  0  0        3
7  2  0  2        2
8  0  2  2        2
9  2  0  0        2
```

Here's another way to do it, but I am only providing this as an example of the "power" (I don't know if that's the right word...) of Python. This is actually the way I initially solved your problem, but thought it would be a little much only to provide this. If I were you, I would prefer `numpy.where`. But this is just for demonstration's sake:

```
# Here is where we use a dictionary to get the new values from the final column
>>> new_values = {c: [df.loc[idx, 'label_x'] if val == 1 else val for idx, val in enumerate(df[c])] for c in df[list(filter(lambda x: x != 'label_x', df))]}
>>> new_values
{1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], 2: [2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], 3: [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]}

# We can just create a new dataframe with the "new" columns made above
# and the original label_x column
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame({**new_values, **{'label_x': df['label_x'].values}})
>>> new_df
   1  2  3  label_x
0  0  2  2        2
1  0  2  2        2
2  0  3  0        3
3  0  0  0        0
4  0  0  0        0
5  0  0  0        2
6  0  0  0        3
7  2  0  2        2
8  0  2  2        2
9  2  0  0        2
```

And, look at that! We get the same answer.

For more information on what's going on with all of those `**`s, please see [Unpacking generalizations in Python 3](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/02/21/python-3-unpacking-generalizations/). It's effectively syntax for merging dictionaries.

You could also look into doing this, basically iterating through each column's corresponding list in `new_values`:

```
for c in [1,2,3]:
    df[c] = new_values[c]
```

There are lots of ways to skin this cat!

Comment: Thank You, this seems to be perfect! I have been running round in circles for too long. The flexibility of knowing of both solutions is appreciated. Is the where method preferred for much larger data frames?{9000, 600}

Comment: 600 columns shouldn't be *too* much of an issue. NumPy is usually the preferred solution if speed is a concern, since it's mostly written in a much-faster C on the back end. Please upvote and accept if this solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with just `numpy`, too.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1], 2: [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0], 3: [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0], 'label_x': [2,2,3,0,0,2,3,2,2,2]})

1  2  3  label_x
0  0  1  1        2
1  0  1  1        2
2  0  1  0        3
3  1  1  1        0
4  1  0  0        0
5  0  0  0        2
6  0  0  0        3
7  1  0  1        2
8  0  1  1        2
9  1  0  0        2
```

And, this

```
mask = df.values[:, :-1] == 1
df.values[:, :-1] = np.where(mask, mask * df.values[:, -1:], df.values[:, :-1])
```

Yields,

```
 1  2  3  label_x
0  0  2  2        2
1  0  2  2        2
2  0  3  0        3
3  0  0  0        0
4  0  0  0        0
5  0  0  0        2
6  0  0  0        3
7  2  0  2        2
8  0  2  2        2
9  2  0  0        2
```